# Declaring Dynamic SqlParameter variables (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create a loop that creates a dynamic SqlParameter variables based on the length of an array. Here's a pseudo-code I have attempted:

```
for(i=0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    SqlParameter [new variable name] = new SqlParameter;
    [new variable name] = da.SelectCommand.CreateParameter();
    [new variable name].ParameterName = paramName[i]; 
    [new variable name].Value = array[i];
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add([new variable name]);
}
```

The reason for this is to create one method to retrieve the dataset where the methods will call the dataset retrieval method in order to pass two arrays (not using multidimensional array) where the loop will determine the length of the array in order to create a number of new SqlParameter variables before it is sent to stored procedure.

I kept getting two errors - one was unable to create more than one SqlParameter variables and another error that the index went out of the array bounds.

Is there a better way of creating dynamic SqlParameter variables using one method to retrieve the dataset from the database via stored procedure?

One example I have in VB code:

```
prmLicense = da.SelectCommand.CreateParameter
  prmLicense.ParameterName = "@LicensePlate"
  prmLicense.Value = license

  prmState = da.SelectCommand.CreateParameter
  prmState.ParameterName = "@StateIssued"
  prmState.Value = state

  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(prmLicense)
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(prmState)
```

That is the reason why I don't want to create a long method like above and want to use the loop to something like this above.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I tried to build one like this above but I kept getting errors and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get why you need a fresh variable name inside the loop. The name of your parameter seems to be assigned to `paramName[i]` which can easily differ for each parameter. Thus, looks like you can reuse the same variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a dynamic parameter name - the parameter will just be reused in the scope of the loop:

```
for(i=0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    SqlParameter param;
    param = da.SelectCommand.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = paramName[i]; 
    param.Value = array[i];
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I am just baffled about the parameter being reused using the same variable. I thought it would throw an error but am surprised it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Marc: While it does use thr same variable name, the loop assigns a new object instance in each iteration. Looks like you confuse these two, the variable name and the object the variable references.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That make sense. Thanks.